# convert postgres query to django query

Tags: python, django, postgresql, sqlite

I need some help with this query.

```
SELECT  s.nombre as 'habilidad',
        GROUP_CONCAT( a.carrera_id )
FROM    perfiles_alumno a,
        perfiles_alumno_habilidades h,
        perfiles_universidad u,
        segmentacion_habilidad s
WHERE   u.user_id = %s
AND     a.universidad_id = u.id
AND     a.id = h.alumno_id
AND     s.id = h.habilidad_id
GROUP BY h.habilidad_id
ORDER BY a.carrera_id
```

I need to do this query in Django. I can use this in my local environment that runs in SQLite3 but when I push to production it fails because I have Postgres.

is there anybody who can help me?

Answer (score 1):

To convert this SQL to Postgres, change `group_concat` to `string_agg(s.carrera_id, ',')`. But then it won't work on SQLite anymore. You will probably suffer less if you use the same database in both development and production.

Also I think you need to `GROUP BY h.habilidad_id, s.nombre` if you want to know the `s.nombre` of each group.

Also you should avoid interpolating user-supplied values with `%s`, because it is a security risk.